# mvc4 input return to action empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem. Value from input is empty in action method, but value from submit button is ok. Here is my code:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActivateUser", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
            foreach (var users in Model)
            { 
                <li>
                    @users.name<br />
                    <input type="text" id="Bounty" name="Bounty" /><br />
                <button type="submit" name="userId" value="@users.userId" title="go">Go!</button><br /><br />
                </li>
            }
```

and my action code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActivateUser(string Bounty, string userId)...
```

This is strange, because `userId` has got a value, but `Bounty` is empty (`""` value)..
How can I resolve it?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate form for each user. Right now the page is submitting all of the inputs at once and the last one "wins", and it's probably empty.

```
foreach (var users in Model)
{ 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActivateUser", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        <li> @users.name<br />
            <input type="text" name="Bounty" /><br />
        <button type="submit" name="userId" value="@users.userId" title="go">Go!</button><br /><br />
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.